# How to reinstall Xdebug on Mac

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I accidentally removed the `pecl/202209../xdebug.so` folder and file after installing it on my Mac. Then I've tried to reinstall it back by running the `pecl install xdebug` command but it returns back *"pecl/xdebug is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.5 install failed".*

I've checked the path (`/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.9/pecl/`) but both the folder and the file (xdebug.so) do not exist.

When I run the `php -v` command it returns two warning as below:

> PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

> Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

I've also tried reinstalling PHP back to the latest version, but the results are the same.

Is there a way I can manually copy the `xdebug.so` file into the folder? Or is there any other way to reinstall it?

Comment: What happens if you run `pecl uninstall` first? There's also `pecl package-validate` but I don't really know what it's meant to do.

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález, i use pecl uninstall xdebug and it work!. thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

You can run:

```
pecl install -f xdebug
```

The `-f` ignores that your PECL installation thinks it has already installed Xdebug, and will then install it again.

Comment: Hi Derick. thanks for your answer. I've mange to fix the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: No! Not actual! xdebug was removed from pecl!

No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"